# How to set word wrap in OO Basic Macro?

Tags: openoffice-calc

So I am pulling data from an Open Office Database and placing it in my Sheet.

I have this all working.  However I would like to set word wrap and autofit on one of the cells to make sure it wraps and expands.

I get my cell like this:

```
oCell=oSheet.getCellByPosition(2,i)
```

This is working but I can't find the API to actually set those properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documented](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Spreadsheet_common#Wrapping.2C_rotation) way seems to be:

`oCell.setPropertyValue( "IsTextWrapped", True )`